# C++ Seg fault on allocating with new []

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program that must iterate through massive text files, and have encountered a problem using `new []` and `delete []` on very large files. The problem occurs when this function is called for the 79,998th time.
I have narrowed the problem down to this function, which executes perfectly for the first 79997 calls, but seg faults on the 79998th execution.

Through gdb, I have narrowed the problem down to this line.

```
*result = new char [end_index_exclusive - start_index_inclusive + 1]();
```

I can only suspect that `delete []` is not actually releasing the memory back to the system, and so there is some issue with too much memory allocated on the heap.

```
void getNewSubstring (char ** result, char * charArray, int start_index_inclusive, int end_index_exclusive){
   if (*result != NULL)
            delete[] *result;
     *result = new char [end_index_exclusive - start_index_inclusive + 1](); //+ 1 for null terminating char
     for (int x = start_index_inclusive; x < end_index_exclusive; x++)
             (*result)[x - start_index_inclusive] = charArray[x];
     (*result)[end_index_exclusive - start_index_inclusive] = '\0'; }
```

This is the error message from gdb :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

0x000000337007aaf9 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6in...--605-- VALGRIND

thanks

Comment: Why are you using pointers? And `new` and `delete`? And dynamic allocation for chunks? Why not memory map the file? So many questions.

Comment: Why do you have a () after the "new" declaration?

Comment: @Dreggman45 it value-initializes (zero-initialize in this case), the allocated buffer, and pointlessly so in this case, since everything just zero-filled is about to be overwritten with source content and the hand-set terminator. If your comment was to point out the pointlessness of it, good call.

Comment: it seems you re-use the result pointer somehow, so i would recommend to null it after deleting / freeing the memory behind it. This minimizes the risk for a dangling pointer...

Comment: Shouldn't `new` throw if there is to little free memory, rather than segfault? Are you sure `end_index_exclusive - start_index_inclusive + 1` is positive?

Comment: Seems that either you deleted/overwrote/corrupted the pointer else where, or you have a memory corruption else were,  or the start and end intexes are very hug and overflow.  Could you check their value at the moment of the crash ?

Comment: as @yussuf pointed out make sure you are nulling the pointer after deleting it. Implementations vary. C++ does not guarantee delete will null the pointer. Some do, some don't.